# force users to make a selection from drop-down box

Tags: javascript, asp.net, detailview

I am trying to make sure that users must select something from the drop-down box so i am using a javascript to check if they have selected something from the drop down box before the data is written into the database.  I have a button in a DetailView and i am not able to access the button id here. i want the user to get warning when they hit the insert button if they have not selected anything from the drop-down.  The selection in the drop-down should not be this "--Select Metric Name--"

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="DV_InputForm" runat="server" Height="69px" Width="763px" AutoGenerateRows="False"
                CellPadding="3" BorderColor="#DEBA84" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" OnItemInserting="DV_InputForm_ItemInserting"
                OnModeChanging="DV_InputForm_ModeChanging" BackColor="#DEBA84" DefaultMode="Insert"
                CellSpacing="2" Style="margin-top: 0px">

                <Fields>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Metric Name:">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblMetricName" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.MetricName") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>

                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_NewMetricName" DataTextField="NAME" DataValueField="NAME"
                                runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" Width="400" Height="25" AppendDataBoundItems="true"
                                DataSourceID="DD_METRIC_DS">
                                <asp:ListItem Text="--Select Metric Name--" Value="--Select Metric Name"></asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>

                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Button ID="btnNew" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="New"
                                Text="Create New Server Monitoring" Font-Bold="True" BorderColor="#003366" BorderStyle="Groove"
                                Height="30px" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <InsertItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Insert" OnClientClick="return validate();"
                                Text="Insert" />
                            &nbsp;<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel"
                                Text="Cancel" />
                        </InsertItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Fields>
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#A55129" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <EditRowStyle BackColor="#FFFFCC" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#003366" />
```

here is my javascript:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
         function validate() {
             var flag = true;
             var dropdowns = new Array(); //Create array to hold all the dropdown lists.
             var gridview = document.getElementById('<%=DV_InputForm.ClientID%>'); //GridView1 is the id of ur gridview.
            dropdowns = gridview.getElementsByTagName('Select'); //Get all dropdown lists contained in GridView1.
            for (var i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
                if (dropdowns.item(i).value == 'Select') //If dropdown has no selected value
                {
                    flag = false;
                    break; //break the loop as there is no need to check further.
                }
            }
            if (!flag) {
                alert('Please make selection from the drop-down and click the insert button again.  Thanks');
                document.getElementById('<%=Button1.ClientID%>').style.visibility = 'hidden';
            }
            return flag;
        }
</script> 

                    <RowStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
                </asp:DetailsView>
```

i am not able to compile it now because it does not like this: `<%=Button1.ClientID%>` and i am getting red line under the Button1.  It seems the way i am accessing the Button1 in the DetailView is wrong.
    `<%=Button1.ClientID%>`

Comment: Can you update your question and explain what currently happens when they click the "Insert" button?

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the button before trying to access it's attributes, since it's in your detail view.

Something like this :

```
<%=((Button)DV_InputForm.FindControl("Button1")).ClientID%>
```

Comment: i have tried but the java-script did not fire the warning message, not sure why it is that..

Comment: Maybe it's because flag is always false? Could you check with some javascript debugging tools the value of the flag var? From what I see in your code, you seems to be checking if your select has been "selected", maybe you could use SelectedIndex instead?

Instead of checking the value of dropdowns in your loop, try something like this to see if an option is selected :     dropdowns.item(i).selectedIndex !== "-1";

Answer (score 0):

If you need to refer to server side controls using client side JavaScript, then I find it's generally easier to set the control's clientidmode to 'static' - then you can give it whatever ID you want, and you know it'll have that ID on the page, so you can write your JavaScript to use that.

Answer (score 0):

This could be one approach

Add `CssClass` attribute to button as

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Insert" OnClientClick="return validate();" CssClass="UniqueClass"
                                Text="Insert" />
```

and access it by classname as below.

```
  var btn= document.getElementsByClassName("UniqueClass");
  var Button1 = btn[0];
```

**Beware**

`getElementsByClassName` will return array of elements for given class name so make sure its unique or access it using proper index.